# Emberjs Routing: Page reloads on every link click

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have an Ember js app, with pushstate enabled. Say I am on a page `www.xyz.com/start` and I have proper link on the page (`www.xyz.com/abc/def`) and I have defined route in ember for `/abc/def`. But every time I click on the link, the page is reloaded instead of directly being served by the Ember router. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: By attaching related code so that we don't have to use our crystal balls :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the link-to helper instead of basic a href links.

```
{{#link-to 'abc/def'}}go to def{{/link-to}}
```

Where 'abc/def' is the route name.

See : http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

Answer (score 0):

When you say a "proper link" do you mean an `<a href>` tag? If so, you should be using the {{link-to}} helper instead. See http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/